# Running JQuery only if the page has POST data

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a page that I would like a block of jQuery code to run ONLY if the page has already been submitted through a form and has POST data. Currently I have the item running using .onload but I want it to only do that in the situation someone has already hit submit. I am not sure what the best way to do this is.

Is there a simple condition check for this? The page, when submitted, calls itself if that makes any difference.

Comment: Checking `$_POST` doesn't work for you?

Comment: `if($_POST){ echo '<script src="yourAwesomScript.js"></script>'; }` doesn't work?

Comment: If the page has been submitted, the browser is not going to run any Javascript until the page is reloaded.

Comment: I don't think code is necessary, all I'm asking is there some function or check that is available in jQuery that can check if a page has been submitted and has POST data.

Comment: Why did you tag PHP? jQuery doesn't ever receive post data because it runs client-side...

Comment: Its funny how on this site most people don't help but proceed to criticize what people wrote or tagged. My questions is very simple but all I get are rude comments and little help. Why don't you try to help people instead of putting people down.

Comment: Folks aren't being intentionally rude @bradc14 it is just that the question is not what SO expects.Please read [How to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Good questions show what you have tried, what didn't work and what you expected. If all you're asking for is a function, as you did in your comment, that is considered a close reason here at SO - "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not check whether a page has `POST` data or not via `JavaScript`. You can do it by `PHP` and with that you can call `JavaScript`

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST))
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        runJquery();
         </script>';
?>
```

`runJquery()` is the `JavaScript` function which will do what you want if their is any `POST` variable in the page.

Comment: Thank you for helping, this worked for me and did not think of this so I appreciate your help instead of how other people respond negatively.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding this conditional to your PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['x'])){
    ...your code here..
}
```